# Converting a contour plot from standard R to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am struggling to find how to convert a contour plot in standard R to a contour plot in ggplot2.

In R, the arguments for the function contour are 2 vectors of values, and a matrix of values which are to be plotted.

For example, consider the following code

```
X=seq(from=1,to=100,length=100)
Y=seq(from=300,400,length=100)

M=matrix(NA,100,100)

for (i in seq_along(X)){
  for (j in seq_along(Y)){
    M[i,j]=log(j)*sqrt(i)
  }
}

contour(X,Y,M)
```

The M is a 100x100 matrix and each entry is a function of each element in X and Y. **This code produces no errors**.

Now I am struggling to convert this example into ggplot.

I try the following code

```
d=data.frame(X,Y,M)
ggplot(d,aes(x=X,y=Y,z=M))+stat_contour()
```

Now it seems to me that usually the variable z is meant to be a vector of length 100 as well. I feel what I need to do is repeat the vector X for each element in Y, and repeat the vector Y for each element in X so that both X and Y are 100x100=10,000 elements long. But this does not seem right to me, nor do I know how to do this. Is there a simpler way of converting to a ggplot contour from an R contour?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ggplot library likes the data in a "tidy" format.  In this case, 3 columns one each for X, Y and Z.

The key to solving this problem is getting all of the combinations of X & Y and converting your square M matrix to a vector.  The `expand.grid` function will generate a dataframe of all of the combinations of X&Y

```
X=seq(from=1,to=100,length=100)
Y=seq(from=300,400,length=100)

M=matrix(NA,100,100)

for (i in seq_along(X)){
  for (j in seq_along(Y)){
    M[i,j]=log(j)*sqrt(i)
  }
}

contour(X,Y,M)

#create all of the combinations of x&y
d<-expand.grid(X, Y)
names(d)<-c("X", "Y")

#Convert from a square matrix to a single vector
d$M<-matrix(M, ncol=1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=X, y=Y ,z=M))+stat_contour()
```

[image]